# Multivariate symmetric polynomial system

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

Consider the following system of polynomial equations in $x_1,\ldots,x_6$:

\begin{eqnarray*}
x_1x_2 - α & = & 0\\
x_3x_4 - β & = & 0\\
x_5x_6 - γ & = & 0\\
x_1x_4+x_3x_2 - δ & = & 0\\
x_1x_6+x_5x_2 - ε & = & 0\\
x_3x_6+x_5x_4 - ζ & = & 0
\end{eqnarray*}
where all constants are strictly positive.

Now assume that $x_1= c>0$, which makes the system overdetermined.

Suppose also that real solutions to the resulting determined system exist when any of the last three equations is removed from it.

Where should I look for conditions that ensure that real solutions exist for the original system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I may have made a typo  my Maple in my answer yesterday, because I get a different answer today.

In a "plex" Groebner basis for your system found by Maple (with variable order $x_6, x_5, x_4, x_3, x_2, x_1, \alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta,\epsilon,\zeta$), the first polynomial (which is the only one that doesn't contain any $x$'s) is
$$ 4\,\alpha\,\beta\,\gamma-\alpha\,{\zeta}^{2}-\beta\,{\epsilon}^{2}-{
\delta}^{2}\gamma+\delta\,\epsilon\,\zeta
$$
So that being $0$ is a necessary condition for a solution to exist.  It is not sufficient though: the third polynomial in the Groebner basis is
$$ \left( 4\,{\beta}^{2}\gamma-\beta\,{\zeta}^{2} \right) {x_{{1}}}^{2}+
 \left( -4\,\beta\,\delta\,\gamma+\delta\,{\zeta}^{2} \right) x_{{1}}x
_{{3}}+ \left( \beta\,{\epsilon}^{2}+{\delta}^{2}\gamma-\delta\,
\epsilon\,\zeta \right) {x_{{3}}}^{2}
$$
and unless the discriminant of this (as a quadratic in $x_3$) is nonnegative there will be no real solutions.  For example, with $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=\delta=\zeta=1$ and $\epsilon=2$, the first polynomial is $0$ but there are no real solutions, as the third polynomial is $3 x_1^2 - 3 x_1 x_3 + 3 x_3^2$ with discriminant $-27$.

Note, by the way, that each term involving $x$'s in your system is the product of an odd-indexed and an even-indexed $x$.  Thus the system is invariant under the transformations
$$x_1 \to t x_1,\ x_3 \to t x_3,\ x_5 \to t x_5,\ x_2 \to x_2/t,\ x_4 \to x_4/t,\ x_6 \to x_6/t$$
for $t \ne 0$. In particular, specifying a nonzero value for $x_1$ will not make a difference.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Which monomial ordering did you use to obtain this Groebner basis?

Comment: Thank you for the rejoinder. Yes, this now matches the Mathematica output too.